# When decreasing width of window, design gets messed up. Increasing width = expected results

Tags: javascript, css

See: http://glados.cc/chat/layout.html

If you make the window smaller, the sidebar gets pushed to the bottom of the page. If you make the window bigger, it works. So you can make the window smaller then a tiny bit bigger and it will display both the content and sidebar at the same time, but I'd prefer if you don't have to do that.

I use javascript to resize the left element when the window is resized:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("left").style.width = window.innerWidth - 160 + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, (hope I'm not about to make an ass out of myself) but playing around with the layout, I think I've got you a solution which doesn't need the JS.

I've wrapped the #left div in a shell, which I've positioned absolutely, with the following values:

```
#left-shell {
position: absolute;
right: 155px;
top: 5px;
left: 5px;
bottom:0;
}
```

I've then floated the #right div to the right, and given the left div a 100 percent width.

The same trick should work for the footer, but I just thought I'd throw this out there, to see if it suits your needs.

I've created a fiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z98L3/

Comment: I think it's doing what it's doing in your example, because the native css rules are being processed before the JS has set the width, so in those precious milliseconds, the page is being drawn before the width of the #left element has been updated. That's just a theory though, as I'm no JS expert. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is what is happening - works fine in chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to have helped, and yeah, the scroll bar would also do it! Cheers for my first Stack Overflow rep too. :)

Comment: Okay, well I'm in the middle of repairing a burst water pipe at the mo, but try doing the same trick, using a shell and setting the shell left, right and bottom at 5px, then give it a height, and try width: auto if 100% isn't doing it. Good luck. :)

Comment: I went back to javascript for my patented (not really) Auto-Collapse feature - if the window is less than 600px, the sidebar is hidden! The trick is to make it 3 pixels less, and firefox no longer has that problem. (Chrome never had it in the first place :) Anyway, here is the current page: http://glados.cc/chat/thinlayout.html

Comment: Whatever works best for you. You can also use media queries (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to do that type of style switching. Anyway, best of luck.